# Embedded fonts in SVG not showing correctly in browser

Tags: css, svg, fonts

There is SVG with two different font types: `SymbolMT` for the math expressions and `Hind-Light` for the text.

Both fonts are defined in `@font-face` section in SVG.

The font for the math expression looks fine but the font for the text is not the same as `Hind-Light`.

SVGs are embeded in a web page which is using the same font "Hind-Light".

here is fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/gde58zw9/

An idea how to fix that font for the text ?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="161.501px" height="64.485px" viewBox="0 0 161.501 64.485" enable-background="new 0 0 161.501 64.485" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Hind-Light';
        src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GMgABA') format('woff2'),
        font-weight: 300;
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
    }
    ]]>
```

Comment: sorry it was wrong link, just updated my post with the link

Comment: Both base64 encoded fonts have issues - you can see errors in your dev tools console (OTS parsing error).  Better try to re-encode these fonts with a tool like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org/)

Comment: should I just choose base64 encode and replace generated string with my current one ? `src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,d09G...` this one ?

Comment: Better replace the complete `@font-face` rule, since you should also specify a font-weight (for the Hind light).  You can also reduce the filesize by defining a character subset and ditch the `<![CDATA[`  wrapping - just makes your code slightly more readable.

Comment: I updated my main post with some example, is it what do you mean ?

Comment: Pardon me, you need to rename the font-family since your text elements use "Hind Light" (otherwise the mapping won't work. You don't need multiple font formats woff2 is well supported and more compact.

Comment: so I fixed my post and created new fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p8u4zd6e/
I'm not sure if the second font type 'SymbolMT' is also working properly ? should it be also converted to woff2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Hind Light' is now correctly embedded in your jsfiddle example.

You can also reduce the filesize of the base64 chunk by defining a subset in the [transfonter UI.](https://transfonter.org/)

[image]

But you still see an error message for the 'Symbol MT'.

Unfortunately it's nearly impossible to create a usable subset for embedding since the Symbol MT  has a **custom character encoding "MS Windows Symbol"** (at least the windows version.  [image]

Regular fonts set the summation/sigma) symbol at:

∑ = `&#x2211;` regular font
∑ = `&#xF0E5` Symbol MT

(Data retrieved with [fontdrop](https://fontdrop.info))

Using a desktop application, the Symbol MT encoding gets converted/remapped.
When exporting the svg - the `<text>` element uses the regular encoding `&#x2211;`.

Since 'Symbol MT' doesn't have this codepoint – you see the 'Times New Roman' summation symbol as fallback, which is noticably bigger.

```html
<span class="times">&#x2211;</span> <span class="symbol">&#xF0E5;</span>

<style>
body{
font-size:10vw;
}

.symbol{
  font-family:Symbol;
}

.times{
    font-family:'Times New Roman', serif
}
</style>
```

#### Workarounds

You could base64 encode the original truetype font without any conversion and change the summation symbol to `&#xF0E5` – not very convenient.

Working [codepen.](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/dyKQyZo)

Alternative: Install all used fonts ('Hind Light') locally so they are avaible in all aplications.
Open your svg in your editor (Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator etc.).
Apply the fonts to your text elements.
**Convert all text to paths**.

Actually, this might quite often produce smaller files than embedding font subsets.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 161.5 64.48">
  <path d="M63.89 8.19h-.6V4.91c0-.38-.1-.68-.29-.88-.2-.2-.45-.3-.77-.3-.4 0-.75.15-1.05.46-.29.31-.44.73-.44 1.26v2.74h-.6V3.23h.6v.85c.31-.62.83-.93 1.58-.93.48 0 .86.15 1.14.44.29.29.43.67.43 1.13v3.47zm93.88 8.75h-3.98v-.54c2.09-1.6 3.13-2.93 3.13-3.99 0-.44-.13-.78-.38-1.01s-.59-.35-1.01-.35c-.49 0-.99.19-1.51.57v-.61a2.4 2.4 0 0 1 2.94-.04c.39.32.59.8.59 1.4 0 1.13-.97 2.47-2.91 4.02h3.13v.55zM11.96 20.47h-1.83v6.04h-.61v-6.04H7.7v-.56h4.25v.56zm26 4.77c0 .41-.14.74-.43.97-.28.24-.67.36-1.17.36-.6 0-1.08-.1-1.45-.29v-.62c.44.25.91.37 1.41.37.33 0 .58-.07.76-.21s.26-.32.26-.54c0-.26-.09-.46-.27-.61s-.47-.3-.89-.46c-.4-.16-.71-.34-.95-.55-.23-.21-.35-.5-.35-.86 0-.4.15-.72.44-.95.29-.24.66-.36 1.11-.36.53 0 .95.08 1.23.22v.6a2.46 2.46 0 0 0-1.24-.26c-.29 0-.51.07-.68.2a.63.63 0 0 0-.25.52c0 .13.02.24.07.34.05.1.13.19.25.27a8.47 8.47 0 0 0 .72.36c.46.18.81.38 1.05.6.26.23.38.52.38.9zm1.72-5.57c.08.08.12.18.12.3s-.04.22-.12.29a.4.4 0 0 1-.3.12.37.37 0 0 1-.29-.12.42.42 0 0 1 0-.59.4.4 0 0 1 .29-.12c.12-.01.22.03.3.12zm.01 6.84h-.6v-4.96h.6v4.96zm38.21-6.84c.08.08.12.18.12.3s-.04.22-.12.29a.4.4 0 0 1-.3.12.37.37 0 0 1-.29-.12.42.42 0 0 1 0-.59.4.4 0 0 1 .29-.12c.12-.01.21.03.3.12zm0 6.84h-.6v-4.96h.6v4.96zm24.84-1.27c0 .41-.14.74-.42.97-.28.24-.67.36-1.17.36-.6 0-1.08-.1-1.45-.29v-.62c.44.25.91.37 1.41.37.33 0 .59-.07.76-.21a.67.67 0 0 0 .26-.54.75.75 0 0 0-.27-.61c-.18-.14-.47-.3-.88-.46-.4-.16-.71-.34-.95-.55-.23-.21-.35-.5-.35-.86 0-.4.15-.72.44-.95.29-.24.66-.36 1.11-.36.54 0 .95.08 1.23.22v.6a2.46 2.46 0 0 0-1.24-.26c-.29 0-.51.07-.68.2s-.25.31-.25.52c0 .13.02.24.07.34.05.1.13.19.25.27a8.47 8.47 0 0 0 .72.36c.46.18.81.38 1.05.6.23.23.36.52.36.9zm4.63 1.02c-.39.2-.85.29-1.37.29a2.4 2.4 0 0 1-1.79-.69 2.44 2.44 0 0 1-.69-1.81c0-.8.2-1.42.61-1.88s.93-.68 1.58-.68c.61 0 1.09.2 1.45.6.36.4.54.96.54 1.68 0 .22-.01.4-.04.53h-3.5c.05.55.24.97.57 1.26.33.29.77.44 1.32.44a2.4 2.4 0 0 0 1.34-.33v.59zm-1.69-4.21c-.42 0-.77.15-1.05.44-.28.29-.44.71-.49 1.26h2.93v-.22c0-.45-.13-.81-.38-1.08s-.59-.4-1.01-.4zm27.28 4.46h-.6v-5.74l-1.44.9V21l1.44-.88h.6v6.39zm21.52 0h-.67l1.63-2.55-1.54-2.42h.7l1.21 1.96 1.2-1.96h.7l-1.55 2.43 1.66 2.54h-.71l-1.3-2.08-1.33 2.08zM57.65 29.7c.08.08.12.18.12.3s-.04.22-.12.29a.4.4 0 0 1-.3.12.37.37 0 0 1-.29-.12.42.42 0 0 1 0-.59.4.4 0 0 1 .29-.12.4.4 0 0 1 .3.12zm0 6.84h-.6v-4.96h.6v4.96zm9.38 0h-.6V30.8l-1.43.9v-.67l1.44-.88h.6v6.39zM3.42 18.97H1.99v3.84h-.87v-9.44h2.13c1.1 0 1.92.25 2.47.75.55.5.82 1.21.82 2.12-.02.63-.2 1.18-.53 1.64s-.81.77-1.43.94l2.51 3.99H6.05l-2.37-3.85-.26.01zm-.07-4.83H1.99v4.06h1.53c.69 0 1.22-.19 1.6-.57.37-.38.56-.86.56-1.43-.01-1.38-.78-2.06-2.33-2.06zm27.31 4.83h-1.43v3.84h-.87v-9.44h2.13c1.1 0 1.92.25 2.47.75.55.5.82 1.21.82 2.12-.02.63-.2 1.18-.53 1.64s-.81.77-1.43.94l2.51 3.99h-1.04l-2.37-3.85-.26.01zm-.07-4.83h-1.36v4.06h1.53c.69 0 1.22-.19 1.6-.57.37-.38.56-.86.56-1.43-.01-1.38-.78-2.06-2.33-2.06zm42.25 4.83h-1.43v3.84h-.87v-9.44h2.13c1.1 0 1.92.25 2.47.75.55.5.82 1.21.82 2.12-.02.63-.2 1.18-.53 1.64s-.81.77-1.43.94l2.51 3.99h-1.04l-2.37-3.85-.26.01zm-.07-4.83h-1.36v4.06h1.53c.69 0 1.22-.19 1.6-.57.37-.38.56-.86.56-1.43 0-1.38-.78-2.06-2.33-2.06zm22.65 4.83H94v3.84h-.87v-9.44h2.13c1.1 0 1.92.25 2.47.75.55.5.82 1.21.82 2.12-.02.63-.2 1.18-.53 1.64s-.81.77-1.43.94l2.51 3.99h-1.04l-2.37-3.85-.27.01zm-.07-4.83H94v4.06h1.53c.69 0 1.22-.19 1.6-.57.37-.38.56-.86.56-1.43-.01-1.38-.79-2.06-2.34-2.06zm57.85 8.66h-.85v-4.69c0-.55-.14-.97-.42-1.26a1.47 1.47 0 0 0-1.11-.43c-.58 0-1.08.22-1.5.67s-.63 1.04-.63 1.8v3.92h-.85v-7.1h.85v1.22c.44-.89 1.19-1.33 2.25-1.33.68 0 1.23.21 1.64.63.41.42.62.96.62 1.62v4.95zM7.73 57.96h-.87v-4.41H1.99v4.41h-.87v-9.44h.87v4.23h4.87v-4.23h.87v9.44zm3-9.79c.12.12.18.26.18.43s-.06.31-.18.42c-.12.11-.26.17-.43.17s-.3-.06-.42-.18c-.11-.11-.17-.25-.17-.42s.06-.31.17-.43c.11-.12.25-.17.42-.17s.31.06.43.18zm.01 9.79h-.86v-7.1h.85v7.1zm7.52 0h-.86v-4.69c0-.55-.14-.97-.42-1.26a1.47 1.47 0 0 0-1.11-.43c-.58 0-1.08.22-1.5.67s-.63 1.04-.63 1.8v3.92h-.85v-7.1h.85v1.22c.44-.89 1.19-1.33 2.25-1.33.68 0 1.23.21 1.64.63s.62.96.62 1.62v4.95zm7.71 0h-.85v-1.04a2.44 2.44 0 0 1-2.2 1.15c-.95 0-1.69-.35-2.23-1.04-.53-.7-.8-1.54-.8-2.54 0-1.1.28-2 .85-2.7s1.3-1.04 2.2-1.04c.92 0 1.65.39 2.17 1.18v-3.86h.85v9.89zm-5.18-3.46c0 .81.2 1.47.6 1.99.4.51.9.77 1.5.77.61 0 1.13-.22 1.57-.67.44-.44.66-1.18.66-2.22 0-.52-.07-.98-.22-1.37a2.06 2.06 0 0 0-1.25-1.31 1.93 1.93 0 0 0-2.25.63c-.4.51-.61 1.24-.61 2.18zm11.61 3.46h-.85v-9.9h.85v9.9zm3.08-9.79c.12.12.18.26.18.43s-.06.31-.18.42c-.12.11-.26.17-.43.17s-.31-.06-.42-.17c-.11-.11-.17-.25-.17-.42s.06-.31.17-.43c.11-.12.25-.17.42-.17s.32.05.43.17zm.01 9.79h-.85v-7.1h.85v7.1zm7.63-.55c0 1.07-.29 1.88-.87 2.42-.58.54-1.33.8-2.24.8-.81 0-1.5-.13-2.07-.41v-.84c.58.29 1.25.43 2 .43.71 0 1.27-.19 1.69-.58.42-.39.63-1 .63-1.83v-.92a2.3 2.3 0 0 1-2.13 1.3c-.82 0-1.52-.3-2.09-.91a3.46 3.46 0 0 1-.86-2.46c0-1.06.26-1.94.79-2.63s1.22-1.04 2.08-1.04a2.3 2.3 0 0 1 2.21 1.36v-1.25h.85v6.56zm-5.04-3.03c0 .85.21 1.5.64 1.94s.91.66 1.43.66a2.1 2.1 0 0 0 1.46-.62c.44-.42.66-1.05.66-1.91 0-.98-.21-1.71-.63-2.18a1.87 1.87 0 0 0-2.98.07 3.35 3.35 0 0 0-.58 2.04zm12.35 3.58h-.85v-4.69c0-.55-.14-.97-.42-1.26a1.47 1.47 0 0 0-1.11-.43c-.58 0-1.08.22-1.5.67s-.63 1.04-.63 1.8v3.92h-.85v-9.9h.85v4.02c.43-.89 1.18-1.33 2.25-1.33.68 0 1.23.21 1.64.63s.62.96.62 1.62v4.95zm5.47-.2c-.27.18-.58.27-.94.27-1.34 0-2.02-.69-2.02-2.07v-4.37h-1.16v-.73h1.16v-1.78h.87v1.78h2.03v.73h-2.03V56c0 .81.38 1.22 1.13 1.22.37 0 .69-.11.95-.32v.86zm7.06.2h-.86v-8.22l-2.06 1.29v-.97l2.06-1.26h.85v9.16zm6.89 0h-.84v-2.3h-4.24v-.77l3.67-6.09h1.41v6.09h1.41v.77h-1.41v2.3zm-4.2-3.07h3.36v-5.6l-3.36 5.6zm11.14 5.87h-.85v-9.9h.85v1.04a2.44 2.44 0 0 1 2.2-1.15c.95 0 1.69.35 2.23 1.04.53.7.8 1.54.8 2.54 0 1.1-.29 2-.85 2.7a2.7 2.7 0 0 1-2.2 1.04c-.92 0-1.65-.39-2.17-1.18v3.87zm0-6.31c0 .52.07.98.22 1.36a2.16 2.16 0 0 0 1.25 1.31 1.93 1.93 0 0 0 2.25-.63c.41-.51.62-1.23.62-2.18 0-.81-.2-1.47-.6-1.99-.4-.51-.9-.77-1.5-.77-.61 0-1.13.22-1.57.67-.45.45-.67 1.19-.67 2.23zm10.41 3.31c-.27.18-.58.27-.94.27-1.34 0-2.02-.69-2.02-2.07v-4.37h-1.16v-.73h1.16v-1.78h.87v1.78h2.03v.73h-2.03V56c0 .81.38 1.22 1.13 1.22.37 0 .69-.11.95-.32v.86zm10.21.2h-.85v-1.27c-.37.92-1.12 1.37-2.25 1.37a2.2 2.2 0 0 1-1.64-.62 2.23 2.23 0 0 1-.61-1.64v-4.93h.85v4.69c0 .54.14.96.43 1.25s.66.43 1.13.43a1.9 1.9 0 0 0 1.52-.67c.39-.45.58-1.03.58-1.75v-3.95h.85v7.09zm7.49 0h-.85v-4.69c0-.55-.14-.97-.42-1.26a1.47 1.47 0 0 0-1.11-.43c-.58 0-1.08.22-1.5.67s-.63 1.04-.63 1.8v3.92h-.85v-7.1h.85v1.22c.44-.89 1.19-1.33 2.25-1.33.68 0 1.23.21 1.64.63s.62.96.62 1.62v4.95zm7.74 0h-.85v-1.04a2.44 2.44 0 0 1-2.2 1.15c-.95 0-1.69-.35-2.23-1.04-.53-.7-.8-1.54-.8-2.54 0-1.1.28-2 .85-2.7a2.7 2.7 0 0 1 2.2-1.04c.92 0 1.65.39 2.17 1.18v-3.86h.85v9.89zm-5.18-3.46c0 .81.2 1.47.6 1.99.4.51.9.77 1.5.77s1.13-.22 1.57-.67c.44-.44.66-1.18.66-2.22 0-.52-.07-.98-.22-1.37a2.06 2.06 0 0 0-1.25-1.31 1.93 1.93 0 0 0-2.25.63c-.4.51-.61 1.24-.61 2.18zm16.1 1.02c0 .82-.28 1.45-.83 1.88-.55.43-1.26.65-2.12.65-.97 0-1.8-.21-2.48-.62v-.97a4.43 4.43 0 0 0 2.43.74c.66 0 1.18-.14 1.55-.43.37-.29.55-.71.55-1.25 0-.41-.14-.74-.42-1s-.69-.5-1.22-.74l-.49-.22-.53-.23-.48-.24a3.1 3.1 0 0 1-.47-.29l-.37-.34a1.3 1.3 0 0 1-.32-.42 2.63 2.63 0 0 1-.26-1.11c0-.79.29-1.41.85-1.86a3.3 3.3 0 0 1 2.09-.66c.78 0 1.44.14 1.96.42v.97a3.99 3.99 0 0 0-1.94-.53c-.63 0-1.13.15-1.5.44-.37.29-.56.68-.56 1.17 0 .25.05.48.15.67.1.2.26.38.5.54a6.17 6.17 0 0 0 1.4.74l.74.33c.17.08.38.2.64.37s.46.33.6.5a2.44 2.44 0 0 1 .53 1.49zm4.87 2.26a4.27 4.27 0 0 1-1.26 1.99 2.7 2.7 0 0 1-1.65.55c-.19 0-.36-.02-.53-.07v-.85c.17.05.33.07.48.07 1 0 1.69-.57 2.09-1.71l-2.9-6.9h.98l.96 2.38 1.37 3.42c.06-.21.47-1.35 1.22-3.42l.87-2.38h.95l-2.58 6.92zm13.19.18h-.85v-4.69c0-1.13-.49-1.69-1.48-1.69-.48 0-.92.22-1.29.67a2.67 2.67 0 0 0-.57 1.79v3.92h-.85v-4.69c0-1.13-.5-1.69-1.48-1.69-.49 0-.92.22-1.29.67a2.67 2.67 0 0 0-.57 1.79v3.92h-.85v-7.1h.85v1.16a2.04 2.04 0 0 1 1.99-1.27c1.14 0 1.84.47 2.1 1.4.44-.93 1.14-1.4 2.1-1.4.75 0 1.3.21 1.67.62.36.42.54.96.54 1.63v4.96zm3.03 0h-.85v-9.9h.85v3.86a2.49 2.49 0 0 1 2.17-1.18c.9 0 1.63.35 2.2 1.04s.85 1.59.85 2.7c0 1-.27 1.85-.8 2.54a2.62 2.62 0 0 1-2.23 1.04c-.97 0-1.7-.38-2.2-1.15v1.05zm0-3.58c0 1.04.22 1.78.66 2.22s.96.67 1.57.67 1.11-.26 1.5-.77c.4-.51.59-1.18.59-1.99a3.4 3.4 0 0 0-.62-2.18 1.92 1.92 0 0 0-2.25-.63 2.12 2.12 0 0 0-1.25 1.31c-.13.39-.2.84-.2 1.37zm13.11.07c0 1.05-.3 1.92-.89 2.61a3.05 3.05 0 0 1-2.44 1.03c-1 0-1.79-.34-2.38-1.04a3.86 3.86 0 0 1-.88-2.6c0-1.04.3-1.91.91-2.62a2.95 2.95 0 0 1 2.35-1.06c1.05 0 1.87.35 2.46 1.04.58.69.87 1.57.87 2.64zm-5.7 0c0 .77.22 1.44.65 2 .43.55 1.01.83 1.71.83.78 0 1.38-.27 1.8-.82.43-.55.64-1.22.64-2.01 0-.82-.2-1.5-.6-2.05-.4-.55-1.01-.82-1.83-.82-.74 0-1.32.28-1.74.84a3.27 3.27 0 0 0-.63 2.03zm8.32 3.51h-.85v-9.9h.85v9.9zM58.95 32.91h5.01v.46h-5.01v-.46zm0 1.79h5.01v.47h-5.01v-.47zm-41.7-17.08h7.18v.66h-7.18v-.66zm0 2.55h7.18v.68h-7.18v-.68zm30.35-4.54h.67v3.27h3.25v.66h-3.25v3.25h-.67v-3.25h-3.26v-.66h3.26v-3.27zm38.22 0h.67v3.27h3.25v.66h-3.25v3.25h-.67v-3.25h-3.26v-.66h3.26v-3.27zm26.53.59 2.54 2.53 2.54-2.53.47.46-2.54 2.55 2.54 2.53-.47.48-2.54-2.54-2.54 2.54-.48-.48 2.54-2.54-2.54-2.53.48-.47zm13.58.32v6.07c.35-.07.63-.2.85-.38s.4-.5.56-.95.29-1.25.39-2.41c.09-.96.24-1.62.45-1.98.21-.36.57-.54 1.08-.54.17 0 .43.04.77.12v.23c-.2 0-.34.03-.44.1-.13.1-.24.27-.32.52s-.16.7-.23 1.36a8.6 8.6 0 0 1-.45 2.32 3.6 3.6 0 0 1-1.58 1.7c-.32.16-.68.26-1.08.3v2.83h-.75V23a3.31 3.31 0 0 1-2.67-1.99c-.17-.41-.32-1.19-.45-2.34-.08-.69-.15-1.16-.23-1.39s-.18-.4-.31-.49c-.08-.06-.23-.09-.44-.09v-.23c.38-.08.64-.12.79-.12a1.31 1.31 0 0 1 1.26.92c.11.31.2.84.27 1.6.09 1.13.21 1.92.37 2.37.16.46.34.78.56.97.21.19.5.32.86.4v-6.07h.74zm11.6 2.33h7.18v.68h-7.18v-.68zm-69.05 9.25H55.02v-.37l6.86-8.52-6.86-8.38v-.38h13.1l.28 3.46h-.41c-.11-.94-.37-1.62-.79-2.02a2.46 2.46 0 0 0-1.76-.61h-7.59l5.76 7.04-6.45 7.97h8.39c.48 0 1-.09 1.57-.28.39-.13.71-.36.97-.69.26-.33.47-.85.64-1.55l.41.07-.66 4.26z"/>
</svg>
```

Drawback: you can't select any text, since every text was converted to `<path>` elements.